# Weird behavior of GWTP app when hitting "Go Back" and "Go Forward" button of Web Browser?

Tags: gwtp

I am using GWTP and I found this issue.

I have this code in CustPresenter:

```
private List<String> dataList=new List<String>();
@Ovvrride
public onBind(){
   myTextBox.setText("Test");
   dataList.add("test");
}
```

Ok, now first time opening the page, the page show the textbox has string "Text" & the dataList has "test" value. While on that page, I hit the "Go Back" and "Go Forward" button of Web Browser (like Chrome or IE). When click "Go Back", then of cause it will show the previous page. When clicking "Go Forward" it will show the customer page & I still see the  string "Text" in the textbox of customer page, but dataList has no "test" value?

What is happening?

Is it a bug of GWTP or did i do anything wrong?

Note: I am using GWT 2.50 Last year version

Comment: Few typos in your code mate: you can't call `new List()` because it's an interface (`new ArrayList()` instead) and that annotation should be `@Override` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `onBind()` method is only called once, when you first instantiate the Presenter. So it populates the `TextBox` and `dataList` as you want.

Then when you click back and go forward again what you are seeing is the `View` that was populated by the first call to `onBind()`. Pressing forward does not run `onBind()` again so maybe you are re-instantiating the `ArrayList` somehow and then NOT populating it because `onBind()` has already been called.

Try this:

```
@Override
public onBind(){
   private List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
   myTextBox.setText("Test");
   dataList.add("test");
}
```

Or just change `onBind()` to `onReset()` or `onReveal()`, as those methods get called whenever a presenter is revealed.

**Someone more knowledgeable may want to correct me here though.**

Comment: the way that Google design Presenter Lifecycle (onBind, onreset....) cause a lot of confused as it not behave like a trditional non-ajax page. Ex sometimes it call reset, sometime it won't call but Google didn't clearly state which action (hit back forward?? or revealPlace??) make the reset called? Sometimes I hit back or forward & onBind Called, so we r not so sure how it works

Comment: I think you're a little bit confused about where GWT ends and GWTP begins. Those lifecycle methods (`onBind()`, `onReset()`, `onReveal()`, `onHide()`) are all part of GWTP which is an open-source project now maintained by ArcBees, not a part of GWT itself. You can read more about them (lifecycle methods, they are called) here on the GWTP wiki: https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Presenter-Lifecycle

Comment: I notice you post a lot of questions on here and I just want to say to you: "Keep going! It will all make sense very soon." This type of development is very different to the old style of doing things but once you 'get it' you will never look back. :)